# Which pronoun to replace in this sentence, (Son copain dit: "Explique-moi le probleme, s'il te plait".)

Tags: grammaire

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's either something like this or this.

Il dit:"Le explique-moi, s'il te plait."

Il dit:"Explique-le à moi, s'il te plait."

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence would be:

> Explique-le moi, s'il te plaît

Comment: Il manque un trait d'union